# AlarmManager reset show error System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

After android phone reboot I reset alarmmanager by query date from SQLi to set alarmmanager.

This is class AlarmReset after phone reboot this class query data to use with method setAlarm().

```
public class AlarmReset  extends BroadcastReceiver {

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    DBHelper dbHelper ;
    Cursor cursor;
    String sNotes;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        AlarmUtils au = new AlarmUtils();
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);

        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            // Set the alarm here.

            db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

            String[] queryColumns = new String[]{DBHelper.COL_DATE,DBHelper.COL_RQCODE , DBHelper.COL_VEHICLE_TYPE, DBHelper.COL_OPTION_NAME};
           cursor = db.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, queryColumns,null,null,null,null,null);

                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                    au.setAlarm(context,cursor.getString(0), Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)), "Test !");

                }

            }
            db.close();

    }

}
```

This is class AlarmUtils for create method setAlarm() it set alarmmanager.

```
public class AlarmUtils  extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void setAlarm(Context context, String alarmDate, int rq_Code, String sNotes) {


        String[] parts = alarmDate.split("-");

        String day = parts[0];
        String month = parts[1];
        String year = parts[2];
        Calendar next1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        next1.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(year));//year...
        next1.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(month)-1);  //first month is 0!!! January is zero!!!
        next1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(day)-1);  //1-31

        next1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,19);  //HOUR
        next1.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);       //MIN
        next1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 2);       //SEC

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("Title", "Title");
        myIntent.putExtra("Notes", sNotes);


        PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, rq_Code, myIntent, 0);


        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, next1.getTimeInMillis(), DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS,pendingIntent1);

    }

}
```

When I run this code it show error like this.

```
10-30 00:07:09.889 3303-3303/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.max.driver_app, PID: 3303
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.max.driver_app.AlarmReset: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2438)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:143)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1285)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:818)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
    at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:4600)
    at com.example.max.driver_app.AlarmUtils.setAlarm(AlarmUtils.java:61)
    at com.example.max.driver_app.AlarmReset.onReceive(AlarmReset.java:64)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2431)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:143) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1285) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:818) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

setAlarm(AlarmUtils.java:61) is class AlarmUtils line

> AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)
>   getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

onReceive(AlarmReset.java:64) is class AlarmReset line

> au.setAlarm(context,cursor.getString(0),
>   Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)), "Test !");

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just initialize AlarmManager with context, so that change
 `AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);`

```
to:
```

`AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);`